# how to connect two controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have these two controllers about stories and categories and they work alone. Now I want to add choosing a already created category when I add news. How should I connect them and how should I show all categories in new.html.erb with select tag?

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @stories = Story.all
  end

  def show
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @story = Story.new
  end

  def create
    @story = Story.new(params[:story])

    if @story.save
      redirect_to stories_path, :notice => "Your story was saved"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])

    if @story.update_attributes(params[:story])
      redirect_to stories_path, :notice => "Your story has been updated"
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
    @story.destroy
    redirect_to stories_path, :notice => "Your story has been deleted"
  end
end

class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(params[:category])

    if @category.save
      redirect_to categories_path, :notice => "Your category was saved"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    if @category.update_attributes(params[:category])
      redirect_to categories_path, :notice => "Your category has been updated"
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy
    redirect_to categories_path, :notice => "Your category has been deleted"
  end
end
```

Comment: [This](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with:

```
# app/controllers/stories_controller.rb
def new
  @categories = Category.all
  @story = Story.new
end

# app/views/stories/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @story do |f| %>
  #....
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :title %>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks but in index.html.erb how to view category.title not story.id

Comment: Inside `@stories.each do |story|` use `story.category.title` to show the category title for each story

Comment: Doesn't works, I tried it yesterday but I have this error message: undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Comment: If i use only story.category.title I have no problems but when I add story.title and story.category.title there is a problem. What is the reason?

Comment: If appears you `undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass`, is because when you're creating the story, the relationship with category isn't being saved. Check the category_id field on your DB or using the rails console. If the category isn't strictly required for a story, you could put `story.category.title unless story.category.nil?`

Answer (score 1):

It's not that you need to connect the controllers together. You really just need `StoriesController` to query the category list, and place it into a class variable, so the view can utilize it.

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new
    @categories = Category.all
    @story = Story.new
  end
```

Comment: I tried but I had problems with the category.
<%= select("story", "category_id", Category.all.collect {|p| [ p.title, p.id ] }, { :include_blank => true }) %>
I think that I saved id, but when I want to see title I see #<Category:0x000000035be318> and I do not know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Hey in the controller u can access only the title of the categories. make a array of titles of cattegories rather than the array of category objects.

```
    # app/controllers/stories_controller.rb
    def new
     @categories = Category.all.map(&:title)
     @story = Story.new
    end
```

Comment: Thanks, I fix that problem but I have another one when I want in index.html.erb to view all news with each title of the category not id. I tried this: story.category.title
but I have error message: undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass –